# Calculate heapsize in the last level of a heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, heapsort

is there an function to calculate the heapsize (the max heapsize and min heapsize) of a heap in the **last level**?

For example when the Heapsize is 128.

Is the Heapsize 128, when I have 128 nodes in a binary tree?

Comment: Are you asking about binary heap data structure?

Comment: Yes. @DAle . Are there different heap data structures. I thought it is always a binary tree?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Variants

Comment: ok. There are a lot :D. But do you know a answer to my question about the heapsize ?? @DAle

Comment: Heapsize is number of items in binary heap. What you mean by this term? What is `heapsize in the last level`?

Answer (score 2):

A binary heap is a [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). That gives us a possibility to find the number of levels from the size of the heap:
[image]
Minimal size of the heap with `k` levels (`height(H) == k-1`) is `2^k`, maximal is `2^(k+1)-1`.

Comment: Thank you!! . @DAle. But when I have the heapsize 128. How should the calculation be with your explenation for the max. **2^(128+1)-1**? but 128 is not *k** in my example :/

Comment: @flowers1234 What is a `heapsize`? A number of elements in the heap?

Comment: I think it is the number of nodes. So, with _k_ we mean the height of a heap. And therefore I have to know how many levels my tree has with 128 nodes, right? . And then I can caluclate the max numbers in my last level with the formular `2^(k+1)-1`? Sorry, for the circumstance. @DAle

Comment: If you have 128 elements in the heap (`size(H)` is the formula above), the number of levels will be `k = height(H) + 1` (it will be `8` levels). "max numbers in my last level"? The number of elements in the `kth` level (zero-based) would be `2^k`. The maximal possible size of the heap with `k` levels would be `2^(k+1)-1` as written in the answer.